# Waiting for fence causes a warning and application freeze

Tags: vulkan

I submit a queue and specify a fence. Just before the submission, I print the fence:

```
qDebug() << "submitting fence: " << cmdFence;
vkQueueSubmit(gfxQueue, 1, &submitInfo, cmdFence);
```

Here are the results of the last 3 submits:

```
submitting fence:  0x145
submitting fence:  0x142
submitting fence:  0x145
```

Somewhere else I have a code that should wait for a fence:

```
qDebug() << "waiting for fences";
for(auto f : activeFences)
    qDebug() << "fence " << f;

if(vkWaitForFences(m_moduleData.deviceData.device,
                   static_cast<uint32_t>(activeFences.size()),
                   activeFences.data(),
                   VK_TRUE,
                   UINT64_MAX) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    throw std::runtime_error{"failed to wait for fences"};
}
```

As can be seen, I'm printing the fence as well before waiting and this is what I get just before `vkWaitForFences` call:

```
waiting for fences
fence  0x142
```

The same fence `0x142` which was submitted earlier! But the validation layer produces the warning:

```
vkWaitForFences called for fence 0x142 which has not been submitted on a Queue or during acquire next image.
```

And the application freezes probably in an infinite wait. But why?

Comment: Can you *prove* that the fence was submitted? Submitted *after it was reset*? The fact that I can see a repeated fence shows that you've reset that fence at least one. So clearly you're resetting fences.

Comment: @NicolBolas you're right. I double checked the code and it seems there's a possibility that `vkWaitForFences` can be called between `vkResetFences` and `vkQueueSubmit`. So basically I'm waiting on the unsignalled fence before submitting the queue. P.S.: I don't know how to be with the question - if you can arrange your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.